# Create a file in JavaScript with a variable for filename and content

Tags: javascript, html, hta

I am trying to create a web control panel on windows. The file is running as an HTA (HTML Application) so it has access to the filesystem. I want it to create a file that's name is the value of `pagename` and its content is the value of `content`.

My code so far:

```
<form id="cpage">
Enter Name of Page to Create: <input type="text" id="pagename"/><br>
Enter Page Contents: <input type="text" id="content"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="formdata()"/>

<script>
function formdata()
{
var filname= document.getElementById("pagename").value;
var content= document.getElementById("content").value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I can understand (sort of) no downvotes, but an upvote is silly, new user or not. Just sayin'. No offense to OP, but please take care to craft well-formed questions, and make sure to pay attention to your own code.

Comment: Could you please provide some more details? I'm not sure what you're looking for

Comment: I want it to create a file that's name is the value of `pagename` and its content is the value of `content`.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Anyway, there's a lot of examples how to do this, just search for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here. One is that this is not valid HTML markup. The `script` tag must be closed. Second of all, your function wasn't closed with a closing brace. Third, you are only declaring one variable. You need two of them.

It should look like this.

```
<script>
  function formdata() {
    var pagename = document.getElementById("pagename").value;
    var content = document.getElementById("content").value;
  }
</script>
```

Also the `onclick` event is fired when the form is submitted, but it doesn't look like it does anything, just creates variables. You could add something like this at the end of your function

```
var string = "Page Name: " + pagename + "\n" + Content: " + content;
alert(string);
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes and i also want it to save it to a file.